# Adding code samples to xml file by publican - foo.c file does not exist

Tags: xml, linux, ubuntu, docbook

I'm new in Ubuntu. I'm trying to create a book by publican. And I need to add code samples to my xml files. I followed the steps which are in the User Guide but I could not do. It says

1.Create the extras directory

```
$ mkdir en-US/extras
```

2.Copy the code file to the extras directory

```
$ cp ~/samples/foo.c en-US/extras/.
```

I created an extras file in my folder. But I do not have a samples file in my own folder also `foo.c`. Maybe this info can be helpful to give an advice to me: I use Eclipse, not any C development environment like DevC++ or VS.. And I will add java and xml code samples to my document. what should I do? Could you help me please?

Comment: You could use an editor like `emacs` to create files like `foo.c`, you don't need Eclipse or an IDE for that (and you could compile with e.g. `gcc -Wall -g foo.c -o foo` in a terminal)

Comment: I wrote that command line in terminal:

gcc -Wall -g foo.c -o foo
gcc: error: foo.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

Comment: You need to run that command in the right directory (the one containing `foo.c`, go in it with `cd`), or to use an editor to create the `foo.c` file, e.g. `emacs foo.c`